# web api return complex object not getting serialized

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to return a complex object with Linq.Dynamic includes, when I am going to return it from the WebAPI I am seeing the object well formed but when I see it in the response I don't see the list I am pretending to send.

```
return await context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.ListOfPhones).FirstOrDefault(c => c.customerId == customerId);
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has experienced this, the fix was really easy, I just realized that I forgot the [DataMember] in the class.

```
[DataMember]
```

public virtual ICollection ListOfPhones { get; set; }